# If entropy increases with time, are humans' thoughts becoming more random as time increases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, general-relativity, cosmology, entropy

If entropy increases with time, are humans' thoughts becoming more random as time increases? What effect would entropy have on the brain over generations from the absolute space-time coordinate? Are we slowly becoming more irrational, random, and chaotic?

Curiosity

Comment: *the absolute space-time coordinate* What absolute space-time coordinate?

Comment: Genesis?  BigBang ?  IDK

Comment: That does happen after you die and your body no longer maintains its complex, non-equilibium state.  At that point, your brain's rationality deteriorates very quickly....

Answer (score 1):

Living organisms (including humans) are not isolated systems, so their entropy does not need to increase with time. In fact, living organism can maintain a state of relatively low entropy by taking in free energy from their environment, at the cost of increasing the the total entropy of the universe.

Comment: Thanks. I am not an expert in any of the related fields. The question suddenly came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Entropy increases with time in closed thermodynamic systems where there is no incoming energy source. Human brains maintain order by metabolizing energy sources, as do all living things.

The functioning of human brains has nothing to do with absolute space-time coordinates (which in fact do not exist).

Human irrationality has nothing to do with thermodynamics.

Comment: Thanks. I am not an expert in physics or any of the related fields. I am a roboticist, but the question suddenly came to my mind this early morning.

Comment: @Hassen The same entropic argument would say that robots are becoming more random.